# Python. Selenium. raise AttributeError("move_to requires a WebElement") AttributeError: move_to requires a WebElement

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, test-automation, pytest

У меня есть код:

Метод ActionChans:

```py
# движение мышкой к элементу с последующим кликом по нему
def rat_race(self, element):
    return ActionChains(self.driver).move_to_element(element).click().perform()
```

непосредственно метод теста:

```py
def click_enter_with_mouse(self):
    return self.rat_race(self.account_locators.BTN_VHOD)
```

локатор:

```
BTN_VHOD = (By.XPATH, ".//div[@id='new-auth']/button")
```

с таким кодом при прогоне теста получал ошибку

> AttributeError: move_to requires a WebElement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

для корректной работы нужно было поправить данную часть кода, где я бы добавлял не просто локатор, а метод который находит этот элемент или даже метод с явным ожиданием

Корректный вариант

```
    def click_enter_with_mouse(self):
        return self.rat_race(self.elements_is_clickable(self.account_locators.BTN_VHOD))
```

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка возникает, потому что метод move_to_element в классе ActionChains требует в качестве аргумента объект типа WebElement, а не локатор. Вы должны сначала найти элемент с помощью метода find_element, а затем передать его в метод move_to_element.

```
def rat_race(self, locator):
    element = self.driver.find_element(*locator)
    return ActionChains(self.driver).move_to_element(element).click().perform()
```